# How to debug - two errors: undef. control sequence fc@.. and missing \endcsname

Tags: errors, debugging, undefined

I read many posts but I found nothing.

I have a legacy project which I used to run in an old ubuntu 14 with its tex packages. Now, I want to rebuild the old project with a modern texlive suite (archlinux). The problem is the amount of code, impossible to put a small snippet to show you.

This is the minimal example of using my "legacy library".

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\input{/mnt/repositories/latex/latex-my/imports/latex-doc/headers_begin.tex}
\setlang{en}
\renewcommand{\docOwner}{owner}
\renewcommand{\docDate}{TODAY}
\renewcommand{\docVersion}{version}
\renewcommand{\docEmail}{email}
\renewcommand{\docTitle}{title}
\newcommand{\docAuthors}{authors}
\renewcommand{\docCopyright}{2016-2017}
\renewcommand{\docListingFont}{dejavu}
\renewcommand{\structnextlength}{\shortnext}
\renewcommand{\tocWithContents}{book}
\renewcommand{\tocWithTables}{simple}
\renewcommand{\tocWithFigures}{simple}
\renewcommand{\tocWithListings}{book}
\renewcommand{\tocWithInject}{book}
\renewcommand{\tocWithInjectAck}{book}
\renewcommand{\tocWithInjectSummary}{book}
\renewcommand{\tocWithTitle}{blank}
\renewcommand{\tocWithSpace}{book}
\renewcommand{\headersLayout}{normal}
\renewcommand{\docHeader}{header}
\renewcommand{\snippets}{styled}
\input{/mnt/repositories/latex/latex-my/imports/latex-doc/headers_end.tex}
\begin{document}
\setlang{en}
\begin{primary}[Introduction]{Introduction}
\label{sec-4}
\phantomsection
The introduction.
\end{primary}\clearpage
\end{document}
```

It depends if I set \setLang{en} or \setLang{es}, I get two different errors:

With \setLang{en}

```
❯ pdflatex semi.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./semi.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3

... I need to cut some lines because of stackexchange limits...

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def)))

Package csquotes Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes' on input line 26.

(./semi.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/omlpxmi.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/omspxsy.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/omxpxex.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/upxexa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/t1pxr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-pdfdoc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-utf8.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fc-spanish.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
\fc@orddef@ult #1->\fc@textsuperscript
                                       {#1}
l.26 \begin{document}

? q
OK, entering \batchmode%
```

With \setLang{es}

```
❯ pdflatex semi.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./semi.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/mnt/repositories/latex/latex-my/imports/latex-doc/headers_begin.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)

... I need to cut some lines because of stackexchange limits...

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-pdfdoc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-utf8.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/ot1pxr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/upxmia.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/upxsya.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/upxsyb.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pxfonts/upxsyc.fd)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \<let>-command
l.26 \begin{document}
```

Any clue how to debug the error here? Any guess from the output/log/error messages? I am completely lost with this type of debugging info.

I tried comment some "\input" that I have in the legacy library, but some parts are related to others and is hard as hell to "remove parts".

Is there any type of backtrace mechanism to find the original line of my library that is creating this errors at the beginning? Or at least the package (amsmath, etc).

**Update 07/04/2017**

More info with the `\tracingall` (last lines):

```
\@empty ->
{\noexpand}

\@gobble #1->
#1<-\getrefbykeydefault {##1}{}{??}

\def #1#2{->\<def>-command \expandafter \noexpand \csname \expandafter \@gobble
 \string #1\@empty \endcsname \@gobble {
#1<-\pageref
#2<-##1
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{\expandafter}
{\string}

\@gobble #1->
#1<-\

\@empty ->
{\noexpand}

\@gobble #1->
#1<-\getrefbykeydefault {##1}{page}{0}

\NROrg@ifthenelse #1#2#3->\let \bbl@temp@pref \pageref \let \pageref \org@pager
ef \let \bbl@temp@ref \ref \let \ref \org@ref \@safe@activestrue \org@ifthenels
e {#1}{\let \pageref \bbl@temp@pref \let \ref \bbl@temp@ref \@safe@activesfalse
 #2}{\let \pageref \bbl@temp@pref \let \ref \bbl@temp@ref \@safe@activesfalse #
3}
#1<-\equal {\docSubtitle }{}
#2<- \large {\ }\\
#3<- \large {\docSubtitle }\\

\let #1->\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \HyPsd@@LetCommand \expandafter
 \expandafter \expandafter {\expandafter \@gobble \string #1\@empty }
#1<-\bbl@temp@pref
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\string}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}

\@gobble #1->
#1<-\

\HyPsd@@LetCommand #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \csn
ame iftrue\endcsname \pdfstringdefWarn \let \expandafter \@gobble \else \expand
after \ifx \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \csname iffalse\endcsname \pdfstri
ngdefWarn \let \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@gobble \else \<let>-com
mand \expandafter \noexpand \csname #1\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \e
ndcsname \fi \fi
#1<-bbl@temp@pref\@empty
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@empty ->
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{changing \bbl@temp@pref=undefined}
{into \bbl@temp@pref=\relax}
{\ifx: (level 5) entered on line 27}
{false}
{\else: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 27}
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@empty ->
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{\ifx: (level 6) entered on line 27}
{false}
{\else: \ifx (level 6) entered on line 27}
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@empty ->
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\fi: \ifx (level 6) entered on line 27}
{\expandafter}
{\fi: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 27}
{\noexpand}

\pageref #1->\HyPsd@@pageref #1*\END
#1<-\let

\HyPsd@@pageref #1*#2\END ->\ifx \\#2\\\HyPsd@@@pageref {#1}\else \expandafter
\HyPsd@@@pageref \fi
#1<-\let
#2<-
{\ifx: (level 5) entered on line 27}
{true}

\HyPsd@@@pageref #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname r@#1\endcsname \relax ??\else \e
xpandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \ex
pandafter \@car \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@gobble \csname r@#1\en
dcsname {}\@nil \fi
#1<-\let
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\let #1->\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \HyPsd@@LetCommand \expandafter
 \expandafter \expandafter {\expandafter \@gobble \string #1\@empty }
#1<-\endcsname
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\string}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}

\@gobble #1->
#1<-\

\HyPsd@@LetCommand #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \csn
ame iftrue\endcsname \pdfstringdefWarn \let \expandafter \@gobble \else \expand
after \ifx \csname #1\expandafter \endcsname \csname iffalse\endcsname \pdfstri
ngdefWarn \let \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@gobble \else \<let>-com
mand \expandafter \noexpand \csname #1\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \e
ndcsname \fi \fi
#1<-endcsname\@empty
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@empty ->
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{\ifx: (level 6) entered on line 27}
{false}
{\else: \ifx (level 6) entered on line 27}
{\expandafter}
{\csname}

\@empty ->
{\expandafter}
{\csname}
{\ifx: (level 7) entered on line 27}
{false}
{\else: \ifx (level 7) entered on line 27}
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \<let>-command
\HyPsd@@LetCommand ...gobble \else \<let>-command
                                                  \expandafter \noexpand \cs...

\HyPsd@@@pageref ...r \ifx \csname r@#1\endcsname
                                                  \relax ??\else \expandafte...

\HyPsd@@pageref ...ifx \\#2\\\HyPsd@@@pageref {#1}
                                                  \else \expandafter \HyPsd@...

\NROrg@ifthenelse ...\bbl@temp@pref \pageref \let
                                                  \pageref \org@pageref \let...

\@title ...ge {\ }\\ }{ \large {\docSubtitle }\\ }
                                                   \vspace {0.1in} \ifthenel...

\pdfstringdef ... \HyPsd@LetCommand \Hy@temp #1{#2
                                                  }\endgroup \ifx #1\@empty ...

\KVS@ProcessorDefault ...e KV@#1@#2\endcsname {#3}
                                                  \fi \fi
\KVS@Parse ...#1}{}{\KVS@Process #1=\KVS@Nil {#3}}
                                                  \KVS@MaybeBreak \KVS@IfEmp...
<argument> ...se \hypersetup {pdftitle={\@title }}
                                                  \fi \fi \ifx \@pdfauthor \...

\@firstoftwo #1#2->#1

\@begindocumenthook ... be\MessageBreak disabled}}
                                                  \ifx \ttl@Hy@steplink \@un...

\document ...ent \@firstofone \@begindocumenthook
                                                  \ifdim \topskip <1sp\globa...
l.27 \begin{document}
```

I upload the legacy + minimal file (`pdflatex testit.tex`). I needed to remove plenty of things, rename images,... for almost 1 hour and half, but I hope it helps. Just replace the two `\setLang{es}` with `\setLang{en}` to see the other error. Uploaded here: [box test.zip](https://app.box.com/s/98jxb1eh4r9648fiqvlndjggn0ak2cp5).

Comment: the example can not be run at all `\input{/mnt/repositories/latex/latex-my/imports/latex-doc/headers_begin.tex}` is not likely to work anywhere other than your machine

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, that is not a minimal example. First, we cannot use it to reproduce the error you are getting. Second, it is not at all minimal. So it is both too much (irrelevant extras) and too little (missing stuff required to reproduce). This is going to make it hard to help. But `\<let>` looks odd. You can use e.g. `\tracingall` but you will get a lot of output unless you minimise first. In the first case, `\fc@textsuperscript` appears to be undefined.

Comment: I updated the last lines of tracingall. Also, I uploaded the code + legacy library in the same zip. pdflatex testit.tex and change the 2 es with en to see the other error. This should be compiled in both ways (es, en). @cfr

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the post with the code. Now you shouldn't have problems when importing the legacy library.

Comment: People tend to be rather wary of downloading `.zip` files from unknown sources. You'd be better off using a pastebin site if you really can't come up with something sufficiently minimal to post here.

Comment: Your example (in the zip file) works with TeXLive 2015, but not 2016. One of the errors (`\fc@...`) is somehow related to the `fcprefix` package, which did change in 2015. I'll investigate further if I get a chance, but in the meantime you could try further reducing your example to simplify the process.

Comment: @IanThompson really thank you for that info. Before you I was giving up. Any possibility to use everything from 2016 but fcprefix from 2015?

Comment: That might be difficult; packages often load other packages, and there can be a lot of trouble with dependencies. It would probably be easier to install TeXLive 2015 in a separate directory and use that distribution instead.

Comment: I have tried in an Ubuntu 16 but it fails with the same error (fc@orddef...fc@texsuperscript). I installed texlive-full (Provides: 2015.20160320-1 - and every dependecny says 2 2015). Which version did you used @IanThompson?

Comment: The version that works: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`. The version that doesn't: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`.

Comment: @IanThompson which compiling options are you using for tex? (which distro)? I execute `pdflatex testit.tex` and it fails.
I use `pdflatex --version` and I get: 
`pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1... Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0`

Comment: The only difference I can see is that I get `Compiled with xpdf version 3.04` instead of `poppler`, but I don't think this has anything to do with the problem. It's more likely that there were changes during the lifetime of TeXLive2015, so that some files you have downloaded are newer than those on my machine. You could try TeXLive2014. Meanwhile, I've posted a partial answer, to stop the comment thread from getting too long.

Comment: P.S. I've restored the link to the zip file so that others can try your example, but you might get more help if you upload it to as pastebin site, as @cfr suggested.

Comment: Ok, cool. Too long. I will try 2014, but I am really interested in what you are trying (fcprefix, fmtcount) because that could solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this partial answer because the discussion in the comments is getting rather long.

I should start by pointing out that it is quite hard to reduce the example provided by the OP. It's a problem with a complicated document template. Now, the document works for me with my installation of TeXLive2015, but not 2016. Both of these are installed on a Mac (not that this is likely to matter), and the versions are

```
 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
```

and

```
 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)
```

With `en` as the argument to `\setLang` (and using TeXLive2016), I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\fc@orddef@ult #1->\fc@textsuperscript
```

I think this is somehow related to the `fcprefix` package, which is loaded by the [fmtcount package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount). However, the relevant files in the 2015 and 2016 distributions seem to be the same. Near the end of `fmtcount.sty`, I found the following:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%                                                                                                                                                                                       
   \ifcsundef{FBsupR}{\let\fc@textsuperscript\textsuperscript}{\let\fc@textsuperscript\fup}%                                                                                                             
}
```

In view of the error, I tried adding

```
\makeatletter
\let\fc@textsuperscript\textsuperscript
\makeatother
```

to the OP's preamble. This produced a different error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \<let>-command 
l.32 \begin{document}
```

I'll be offline for a few days, and will look at this again when I return. Meanwhile if anyone can shed any light on this, please feel free to edit the above.

**EDIT**

It's probably worth noting that the installation of TeXLive2015 on my machine was probably set up around the time of its release, so changes to the distribution during its lifetime will mean that new downloads will have some updated files. The OP can't get the document to work with TL2015, so it might be worth trying TL2014.

Comment: Did you try adding it after `\BeginDocument`?

Comment: Hi! I tried the previous weekend again.. but with wrong results. Do you know how to proceed (at least in general steps) from your point?